# Image turns pink when compressing it with imagemagick (PHP)

Tags: php, imagemagick

When compressing a image with imagemagick on PHP the result turns pink.

```
$im = new Imagick();

$imgsrc = file_get_contents( $imgFilepathIn );
$im->readImageBlob($imgsrc);    

$im->setImageColorspace(255);
$im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(90);    

$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');                
$im->writeImage( $imgFilepathOut );
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the default transparency color for the jpg (which is pink).

We can overcome this by explicitly setting a new transparency/background color.

```
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
```

and it also seems like

```
$im->setImageColorspace(255);
```

could sometimes create problems